# Should there be standing water in the drain pipe under my second floor shower?

Tags: plumbing, water, shower

When we put a tile floor in the shower we use a drain with a strainer. Screwing the strainer off to replace, I found 3"of standing water at the bottom of the pipe.  There was a little ring of mold on the vertical pipe, but the water was clean.  Was this 2nd floor shower plumbed correct?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it's a trap for your shower, just like you have a trap under your sink. The P trap prevents sewer gases from coming back into the home, which would smell, and possibly cause a methane explosion.

Comment: It's possible that in other houses/installations the traps are further downstream in the plumbing so it's less obvious. In this case, it's right up next to the shower.

Answer (score 0):

One quick question how many inches below the tub drain level is the water? This will help me determine whether it is just simply water that is normally in the P trap or whether the water is higher maybe indicating some sort of blockage or clog but not totally clogged or blocked.